# Mithril simple example demands ReactJS

Tags: mithril.js

Just trying to do simple example using JSX without webpack and npm.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.18.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/babel">
      var MyComponent = {
        view: function() {
          return (
            <main>
              <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </main>
          )
        }
      }

      m.render(document.body, <MyComponent />)
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but getting React error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

I am confused why React has got anything to do with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, JSX produces React code. In order to produce Mithril code, you must set the 'pragma' to `m`. The easiest way to do this is to set the following comment at the top of each JSX file:

```
/* @jsx m */
```